# Unity - shader works differently on Android (OpenGL) and Editor (DX11)

Tags: android, opengl-es, unity-game-engine, directx, shader

I wrote circular cutout sprite shader which works ok in editor & standalone version but behaves incorrectly on Android devices.

In essence it's simple pixel shader:

```
fixed4 frag(pixelData IN) : SV_Target
{
 const float PI = 3.1415;
 float angle = -atan2(IN.texcoord.x - 0.5, -IN.texcoord.y + 0.5) + PI;

 if (angle < _Percent * 2 * PI) //_Percent is in range from 0 to 1        
     return tex2D(_MainTex, IN.texcoord) * IN.color;            
 else
     return float4(1,1,1,0);            
}
```

**Rendering in editor (DX11 on DX9 GPU)**

[image]

**Screenshot from Android (OpenGL - Nexus 4)**

As you can see exactly in the middle there are pixels which should be red

[image]

I'm using Unity 5.0.0f4. Attaching zipped test project: [ShaderTest.zip](http://rachwal.com.pl/ShaderTest.zip) (30kB)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating to newer version of Unity problem resolved itself.

Answer (score 0):

In `atan2`, as the `y` parameter approaches zero from above (eg - `IN.texcoord.x - 0.5 ~= +0`), you're going to start getting values near PI, because you'll get `arctan(y/x) + PI`, where `y ~= 0`, and `arctan(0) = 0` (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2). The Android version is presumably using lower precision floating point operations, and thus this is much more noticeable there. Likely if you zoomed in enough on the desktop version, you'd see pixels that fail your conditional as well.

Comment: From what it says on wiki `atan2` is only undefined when both `x == 0 && y == 0` so this is not the case

Comment: updated answer... the essence of the answer was correct, but the case wasn't quite right.

Comment: "In atan2, as the y parameter approaches zero from above (eg - IN.texcoord.y + 0.5 ~= +0)"
Could you clarify which parameter do you mean?
atan2 is defined as atan2(y,x) but you relate to `-IN.texcoord.y + 0.5 ` which I'm using for x (second) argument.

Comment: Update answer again to correct parameter value... same argument holds.

Comment: [image](http://s17.postimg.org/ef3dpgfjz/YNJv_M.png)
y parameter (first) of atan2 is not 0 (or near) where I placed yellow dot but it still renders incorrectly.